# AudioClip Will Not Play, File Path Incorrect?

Tags: java, audio, applet, nullpointerexception

I created a quick small applet to play an audio clip, but as of right now, no dice.
I have no idea why, and the path to the file is correct. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class PlayAudioClippls extends JApplet {
private URL soundToPlay = getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Brian Murphy\\workspace\\FlagsSOUND\\anthem_mid files\\anthem6.mid");
private AudioClip AC = Applet.newAudioClip(soundToPlay);

public void init()
{
AC.play();  
}

}
```

Here is the exception list

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Unknown Source)
at PlayAudioClippls.<init>(PlayAudioClippls.java:10)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `getReseource` only works for the run-time class-path of the applet.  The `C:` drive is not on that class-path.  For better help provide the location of the HTML and class/Jar files as well as the HTML.  Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for the response, so I put the midi file into the source folder ("getClass().getResource("anthem6.mid");"), and still nothing... would you still like the class/jar files?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20202897/edit) **all** the information I requested into the question.  That is *"For better help provide the location of the HTML and class/Jar files as well as the HTML (used to load the applet)."*

Comment: So, at the moment, I am running the file out of Eclipse as an applet, so I haven't yet made an HTML file for it. The location of the class and jar files are

PlayAudioClippls.class Located in - C:\Users\Brian Murphy\workspace\PlayAudioClippls\bin -

Comment: and the jar file locations are

C:\Users\Brian Murphy\Downloads\eclipse-standard-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins

Answer (score 0):

> [...] the path to the file is correct. What am I doing wrong?

The path to the file is *not* correct, in that you are giving a path relative to the machine's file system, whereas `Class.getResource()` [ordinarily] wants a path relative to one of the directories in the applet's classpath.  You get a `NullPointerException` because your `getResource()` call returns `null` on account of that problem.

Note well: it's only indirectly a matter of the location of the file.  It is *primarily* a question of how the path to it is expressed.  You may put the file in a directory that is on the applet's classpath (perhaps `C:\Users\Brian Murphy\workspace\PlayAudioClippls\bin`) or in a subdirectory somewhere beneath such a directory.  The former is slightly easier than the latter.  In that case, you would want this:

```
private URL soundToPlay = getClass().getResource("/anthem6.mid");
```

"Relative to a directory in the class path" means you specify only the part of the path that follows the relevant class path directory.  That can include subdirectories if you like, so that the applet's resources don't have to all appear in the root of its jar.